# Ordenar duas listas simultaneamente, por notas em ordem crescente, e em seguida por nome

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Criei duas listas, que é de notas e outra é de nomes. O programa deve classificar notas em ordem crescente, mas deve ordenar nomes também.
Testei da seguinte forma:

```
notas = [5, 7, 9, 3] 
nomes = ["Alfredo", "Camila", "Debora", "Joao"]
```

Felizmente deu certo, com o seguinte resultado:

```
[9, 7, 5, 4]
["Debora", "Camila", "Alfredo", "Joao"]
```

Eu testei outra vez:

```
notas = [5, 9, 2, 7] 
nomes = ["Joao", "Debora", "Camila", "Alfredo"]
```

Deu errado no resultado:

```
[9, 7, 5, 2]
['Camila', 'Joao', 'Alfredo', 'Debora']
```

Eu tentei muitas vezes e não consegui resolver.

Meu código:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------
lista_notas = []
backup_notas = []
ordem_list = []
lista_nomes = []
backup_nomes = []
i_to_while = 0
ii_to_while = 0
#---------------------------------------------------------------
def decrescente(notas):
    lista_notas.append(notas)
    backup_notas.append(notas)
    lista_notas.sort()
    lista_notas.reverse()
    return lista_notas, backup_notas
#---------------------------------------------------------------
def descobrindo_posicoes(notas, original):
    ii = 0
    while ii != len(notas):
        ordem = notas.index(original[ii])
        ordem_list.append(ordem)
        ii+=1
    return ordem_list
#---------------------------------------------------------------
def insere_nomes(nomes):
    lista_nomes.append(nomes)
    backup_nomes.append(nomes)
    return lista_nomes, backup_nomes
#---------------------------------------------------------------
def sincronizando_nomes(notas, ordem, nomes, original, original_notas):
    print(notas, ordem, nomes, original, original_notas)
    n = 0
    while n <= len(nomes)-1:
        nomes[n]= original[ordem[n]]
        nomes_resultado = nomes
        n+=1
    print("Antes de programa")
    print(original_notas)
    print(original)
    print("")
    print("Resultado")
    print(notas)
    print(nomes)
#---------------------------------------------------------------
while True:
    if i_to_while == 4:
        break
    decrescente(int(input("Suas notas? (4 notas suportadas): ")))
    i_to_while += 1
#---------------------------------------------------------------
descobrindo_posicoes(lista_notas, backup_notas)
#---------------------------------------------------------------
while True:
    if ii_to_while == 4:
        break
    insere_nomes(str(input("Seus nomes? (4 nomes suportados: ")))
    ii_to_while += 1
#---------------------------------------------------------------
sincronizando_nomes(lista_notas, ordem_list, lista_nomes, backup_nomes, backup_notas)
#---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a ideia é sincronizar as duas listas (ou seja, ordenar as notas, e depois manter a ordem dos respectivos nomes), não precisa dessa complicação toda.

Em vez de ter duas listas, eu sugiro ter apenas uma, guardando tuplas que contém o nome e a respectiva nota (mas também tem uma alternativa com duas listas no final).

Assim, ficaria desta forma:

```py
nomes_notas = []
quantidade = 4
for _ in range(quantidade):
    nome = input('digite o nome:')
    nota = int(input('digite a nota:'))

    # insere uma tupla contendo o nome e a nota
    nomes_notas.append((nome, nota))

# ordena pela nota em ordem decrescente
nomes_notas.sort(key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)
print(nomes_notas)
```

Ou seja, eu leio o nome e a respectiva nota, e depois eu insiro uma tupla - o `(nome, nota)`: repare nos parênteses, eles não são redundantes. Se eu fizesse `nomes_notas.append(nome, nota)`, eu estaria passando dois parâmetros para `append` e daria erro. Ao colocar esse par de parênteses extra, estou criando uma tupla contendo o nome e a nota, e esta tupla é inserida na lista.

Depois, basta ordenar usando o valor da nota (é o que o `key=lambda...` faz, pega o segundo elemento da tupla - o que está na posição `1`, já que a primeira posição é zero), e o `reverse=True` faz com que seja em ordem decrescente.

No final a saída será algo como:

```
[('ciclano', 5), ('trajano', 4), ('beltrano', 3), ('fulano', 1)]
```

Mas se quiser criar listas separadas para os nomes e as notas, basta fazer:

```py
nomes = [ t[0] for t in nomes_notas ]
notas = [ t[1] for t in nomes_notas ]
```

---

Mas se quiser, pode manter os dados em duas listas - o que eu não sugiro, pois se cada nome está atrelado a uma nota, então faz mais sentido agrupar estas informações, em vez de mantê-las separadas e tentar criar todo um esquema complicado para sincronizá-las. Mas enfim, seria algo assim:

```py
quantidade = 4
nomes = []
notas = []
for _ in range(quantidade):
    nomes.append(input('digite o nome:'))
    notas.append(int(input('digite a nota:')))

indices = sorted(range(len(notas)), key=lambda i: notas[i], reverse=True)
notas_ordenadas = [ notas[i] for i in indices ]
nomes_ordenados = [ nomes[i] for i in indices ]
```

Ou seja, eu crio uma lista de índices (os números de zero até o tamanho da lista `notas`), e ordeno esses índices usando como base o valor deste índice na lista de notas (é o que o `key` ali faz, para cada índice, pega a respectiva nota).

Depois, basta pegar os valores dos nomes e das notas, na ordem determinada pela lista de índices.

Reforço novamente que esta é uma opção mais confusa, pois se as notas e os nomes devem estar sincronizados (cada nome tem sua nota), eu prefiro agrupar esses dados e mantê-los juntos, como feito na primeira solução acima.

Answer (score 7):

De forma mais *pythônica*, poderia ser:

### Criando variáveis

```
notas = [5, 7, 9, 3]
nomes = ["Alfredo", "Camila", "Debora", "Joao"]
```

### Juntando listas

```
l = list(zip(nomes, notas))

print(l)
[('Alfredo', 5), ('Camila', 7), ('Debora', 9), ('Joao', 3)]
```

### Ordenando por nota

```
l.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

print(l)
[('Joao', 3), ('Alfredo', 5), ('Camila', 7), ('Debora', 9)]
```

### Separando as listas

```
nomes, notas = zip(*l)

print(nomes)
('Joao', 'Alfredo', 'Camila', 'Debora')

print(notas)
(3, 5, 7, 9)
```